# Invalid response from .well-known/acme-challenge/<token>

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl, certbot

I'm trying to use certbot to obtain an SSL certificate for one of my subdomains. However, one of the challenges fails when trying to test `.well-known/acme-challenges/<token>`. The web server (nginx) returns 404. The precise error is:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for git.domain.com
http-01 challenge for www.git.domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.git.domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.foo.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eXpa7Ub3slbohHh0AZZA-aACo70p15KkJS05aYsN2bY [my-ip-addr]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>", git.domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://git.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WxYfL5t0vLNe7jiIF2TFz1sXyQBH3RcPIVz5de9lQ8M [my-ip-addr]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.git.domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.git.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eXpa7Ub3slbohHh0AZZA-aACo70p15KkJS05aYsN2bY
   [my-ip-addr]:
   "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body
   bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"

   Domain: git.domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://git.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WxYfL5t0vLNe7jiIF2TFz1sXyQBH3RcPIVz5de9lQ8M
   [my-ip-addr]:
   "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body
   bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I have added into my config file:

```
location ^~ '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    allow all;
}
```

But this does nothing. The fact that it is getting a 404 is whats throwing me off. If it was a problem of nginx not allowing access to the file, then wouldn't it throw a 403?

`nginx -t` shows no errors in my config. I have ensured that my DNS info is set up correctly.

Full config (`nginx -T`): https://pastebin.com/a6GcbXai

Last 25 lines of access.log after running certbot: https://pastebin.com/Lp72LWxC

Another thing that puzzles me is that I have 3 other subdomains running on this server, none of which I have had this problem with.

What is happening here, and how do I allow certbot to see this file, so I can get the certificate?

Comment: What is the corresponding entry in the error log?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question so that we can see the full config.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Please see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed by adding the following into my nginx config:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

It works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the quotes `'` around your path specification. Try:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge { ... }
```

Comment: No change. The same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I thought that since `location/ .well-known/acme-challange/` came in the nginx.conf they were bound to the var/www/certbot, However, Certbot uses the URL `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...` to find its challenge/response file.

Nginx uses the [`root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) to convert the URL into a file name by concatenating the `root` value with the ["path" component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) of the URL.

The URL `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>`, would expect to find the file `token` in the directory:

```
/var/www/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge
```

So I have to create the `.well-known/acme-challenge` directory into `var/www/certbot`.