# Certbot standalone fails with error: Some challenges have failed

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

The website runs on Web-hosting server beget.com

I am using Ubuntu 20 If that information is useful.

I am trying to get SSL-certificate with certbot by standalone on my domain ***dmitrysemenyuk.com***

As I understand I get error 404, but I do not really realise how to fix it and what can I do in that way. Any help is appreciated!

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --standalone
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Please enter the domain name(s) you would like on your certificate (comma and/or
space separated) (Enter 'c' to cancel): dmitrysemenyuk.com
Requesting a certificate for dmitrysemenyuk.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: dmitrysemenyuk.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 185.50.25.13: Invalid response from http://dmitrysemenyuk.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Vdk7yVZniKswQwpCUnOyINQQTdlRHuPl8H7JLbxTDng: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

Comment: Check angainst this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/invalid-response-well-known/83631/23

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1060073/invalid-response-from-well-known-acme-challenge-token

Answer (score 0):

In general:

## Start doing what the application asks you to do:

> See the logfile `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`
> or re-run Certbot with `-v` for more details

Comment: This should be a comment, but yes.

Comment: Yea but there is no logs smart guy